# Allow long running admin page in Sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I've got an admin .aspx page that I need to run on an instance to iterate through a bunch of items and fix some Worflow fields that aren't set properly. It's got to get through a lot of items. I ran it on my dev machine and it worked fine. It took a really long time, but completed.

Now, I'm trying to run the same page in the client's environment and I keep getting an HttpException: Request timed out error.

I just need to run this thing once. Any thoughts on why it won't run there and how to make it so I can get it to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET There is a executionTimeout. This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False. This can explain the different behavior on your dev vs production

[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

An other option is the app pool recycle setting.

Comment: That was it. Timeout doesn't apply to debug mode, so I just set debug="true" on the client server temporarily while I ran the script. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Open IIS, and Select "**Advanced Settings**" for your **Application Pool**
- Set the **Ping Maximum Response Time** to a larger number, note its in seconds
- Reset those values back to the original value, once the task is done

Hope This helps